# If the first header value is empty, pandas skip it

Tags: python, pandas

When I have Excel like this:

```
A |  B   | C
  | name | age
v1|  v2  | v3
```

And I try to execute after load data to df:

```
print(df.columns.values)
```

I have output:

```
['name', 'age']
```

Why pandas do not show me first df.columns.values as *null* or *empty string*?

Answer (score 1):

*describe* is a **method** of a *DataFrame*, not attribute.

On the other hand, *columns* is just an **attribute**, so in this
case (without parentheses) you got what you want. You would have got
the column names even without *.values* (which is also an attribute).

Just as in case of other *Pandas* methods, when you print `df.` + a
method name **without parentheses**, you get just this printout.

A "side effect" is here that you get printed the *DataFrame* itself.

Run `print(df.describe())` (**with parentheses** after the method name)
and you should receive the intended printout.

What you see in Excel as the first column is probably the **index**
in *Pandas* and it happens quite often that it has no name,
but further (regular) columns do have their names.

To check it, run `df.info()` and the printout should include some
description concerning the index and then concerning each column.

Comment: Ok, but why pandas do not show me first df.columns.values as null or empty string? Can i fix it somehow?

Comment: I suppose that column *A* in your Excel file has been read as the index. One of methods to do it is to pass *index_col=[0]* to *pd.read_excel()*. Note that *df.columns* yields only names of "normal" (non-index) columns. Run *df.info()* to show all columns with their types.